# sending multiple texts and images to email body

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am sending email through my app using `setMessageBody` i can set body to my mail but my requirement is i want send multiple images and text  [image: as show in image]

Using `addAttachmentData`  twice i can send two images but i want to send text image text image.

Using html is not working in gmail
Is it possible to send like that?

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailView= [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mailView.mailComposeDelegate=self;
            [mailView setSubject:@"ABCD"];
              [mailView setMessageBody:@"Hai" isHTML:NO];
            UIImage * emailimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Iconpaid.png"];
            NSData * emaildata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(emailimage, 1.0);

          [mailView addAttachmentData:emaildata mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"File"];

           // Here i want to add text

          [mailView addAttachmentData:emaildata mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"File"];
            [mailView setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@""]]; //[NSArray arrayWithObject:appDelegate.mechanicEmail]];
            [self presentModalViewController:mailView animated:YES];
```

Comment: added check it @SAMIRRATHOD

Comment: Got any solution?. with below answer.

Comment: trying with your code only that moving all images and text to separate view and then converting it to image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[mailView addAttachmentData:emaildata mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"File"];
```

Use this line to attach how many images you want you can add like this and

```
[mailView setMessageBody:@"Hai" isHTML:YES];
```

Make that `isHTML` = `YES` So that you will get all images in body not as attached file (in embeded body)

Comment: after making isHTML =Yes i am getting all images in body but all textfields are paced on top

Answer (score 2):

You can get a screenshot of a view. Use the following code.

```
UIView *totalContentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[totalContentView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
UIImageView *image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[image1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
[image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];
UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[textLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 50)];
[textLabel setText:@"Its working fine"];
UIImageView *image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[image2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 320, 200)];
[image2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]];
[totalContentView addSubview:image1];
[totalContentView addSubview:textLabel];
[totalContentView addSubview:image2];
[self getAsImageForView:totalContentView forRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
```

and getAsImageForView method is followed,

```
-(UIImage *)getAsImageForView:(UIView *)view forRect:(CGRect)rect;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    CGImageRef tmp = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, rect);//CGRectMake(240, 0, 240, 320)
    UIImage *cuttedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:tmp];
    CGImageRelease(tmp);
    return cuttedImage;
}
```

It will return a image. You can attach this image in your mail.

Comment: i got that idea it was table so how i can send that entire table?

Comment: you should add all the data in a UIView.

Comment: ok i got it but one doubt instead adding all those to sperate view i cant i give direct tableview height there?

Comment: I never add any UITableview in this method instead of totalContentView.[self getAsImageForView:totalContentView forRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)]; . Can you try this once and inform me?.

Comment: Anyway it will take screenshot visible views only. I think so. Try it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29766/discussion-between-sathiamoorthy-and-user1915453)

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem and i find the answer. see following link

[MFMail](https://github.com/aporat/iTellAFriend)

you can set text and image , text and image its easy.

set your message body with this function

```
     - (NSString *)messageBody
     {
         // if we couldn't fetch the app information, use a simple fallback template
         if (self.applicationSellerName==nil) {
             // Fill out the email body text
             NSMutableString *emailBody = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<div> \n"
                                  "<p style=\"font:17px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif\">%@</p> \n"
                                  "<h1 style=\"font:bold 16px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif\"><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"%@\">%@</a></h1> \n"
                                  "<br> \n"
                                  "<table align=\"center\"> \n"
                                  "<tbody> \n"
                                  "<tr> \n"
                                  "<td valign=\"top\" align=\"center\"> \n"
                                  "<span style=\"font-family:Helvetica,Arial;font-size:11px;color:#696969;font-weight:bold\"> \n"
                                  "</td> \n"
                                  "</tr> \n"
                                  "<tr> \n"
                                  "<td align=\"left\"> \n"
                                  "<span style=\"font-family:Helvetica,Arial;font-size:11px;color:#696969\"> \n"
                                  "Please note that you have not been added to any email lists. \n"
                                  "</span> \n"
                                  "</td> \n"
                                  "</tr> \n"
                                  "</tbody> \n"
                                  "</table> \n"
                                  "</div>",
                                  self.message,
                                  [self.appStoreURL absoluteString],
                                  self.applicationName
                                  ];

             return emailBody;

         }
```

Comment: after making isHTML =Yes i am getting all images in body but all textfields are paced on top